# Andare giù - abstract meaning

Tags: word-usage

I know that "andare giù" means "to go down" and that it can have a literal meaning. Example:

> Ho provato ad andare giù ma le pietre sono scivolose.

Can it also be used in figurative meaning, as in the following sentence?

> La temperatura è andata giù.

Comment: Why do you think that the usage in the second  example is figurative?

Comment: @Gio: Nel senso che la temperatura non cammina.

Comment: @Charo - la temperatura sale e scende in senso reale,   non figurato.

Comment: Abbiamo già avuto in passato una discussione futile su cosa sia un senso reale e cosa sia un senso figurato, cerchiamo di attenerci alla sostanza. È abbastanza chiaro che "andare giù" nel senso di camminare in discesa e "andare giù" nel senso di diminuire siano due significati diversi :).

Comment: Mi vengono in mente usi "figurati" di _andare giù_ come "non mi è mai andata giù" (I never dealt with that) oppure "andarci giù pesante" (to be pretty harsh/intense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the expression "andare giù" is a complete synonym of the verb *scendere*. From the [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/andare1/)

> **andàre** [...] *A. giù*, scendere.

And under the heading [scendere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scendere/) we see that among the numerous meanings it can have, the two in the question are present:

> **scéndere** [...] **1.a.** Muoversi da un luogo più alto a un luogo più basso, discendere: *sc. dall’ultimo piano*; *sc. da una scala a pioli*; *sc. dall’albero*; *sc. dalla soffitta, dalla terrazza*; *sc. da un pianerottolo a quello sottostante*; [...] **3.d** fig., diminuire, decrescere: *la temperatura è scesa improvvisamente a zero* o, assol., *continua a sc.*; *i prezzi degli appartamenti non accennano a sc.*; *la benzina è scesa di tre centesimi di euro al litro*.